# How to get data into a regionMap?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to get data via VBA into a RegionMap.
[screenshot from input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTXZF.png)
This Data is dynamic, but you could use this for reproduction.
The string mapInput holds the Range where the data is in and this works right. I have tested this via f8.

If I change the chart type from 140(RegionMap) to any other supported number from the Microsoft documentation, I can use the code and no error is coming up.

I am completely clueless about what I do wrong.
I hope one of you has the answer because there is literally no information available online about the RegionMap.

```
Dim l As String
Dim lastRowR As Long
Dim lastColR As Long
Dim mapInput As String
Dim cCount As Integer
Dim MyChartm As Object
Dim ws As worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("results")
lastColR = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRowR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


l = Split(ws.Cells(lastRowR, lastColR - 2).Address, "$")(1)
mapInput = "A" & lastRowR - 1 - cCount & ":A" & lastRowR - 1 & "," & l & lastRowR - 1 - cCount & ":" & l & lastRowR - 1

Set MyChartm = Sheets("charts").Shapes.AddChart2(494, 140, Left:=offs, Top:=510)
With MyChartm.Chart
    .SetSourceData ws.Range(mapInput)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "map"
End With
```

> error 445: Object does not support this action

The debugger goes to: `.SetSourceData`...

Comment: Are you using Excel 2016? If so, this is (if I read correctly) a known bug. See [this](https://books.google.nl/books?id=qnl_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT543&lpg=PT543&dq=Bill+jelen+excel+2019+xlregionmap&source=bl&ots=zmMNgJutRY&sig=ACfU3U2rggvlRJq15G6Tj7Yz95TuNnIPkg&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ2fDp3MjlAhUSJ1AKHQG2DuoQ6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Bill%20jelen%20excel%202019%20xlregionmap&f=false)

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you provide sample data to work with, or at least a screenshot of sample data so others will be able to reproduce what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry but the table is quite big. I hope the screenshot I have added will help.
Thank you guys for your help